# How to add \cline to a fifth column after a multirow fourth column

Tags: tables

Given my table code below, I would like to add `\cline` to the last column, after the multirow fourth column.

```
\documentclass[10pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
first & second & third & fourth & fifth \\\hline
1 & first & two & \multirow{5}{*}{list} &\\\cline{1-3}
2 & second & three & &\\\cline{1-3}
3 & third & four & &\\\cline{1-3}
4 & fourth &five & &\\\cline{1-3}
5 & fifth & six & &\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I have tried `\cline{1-3,5}`, `\cline{1-3}\cline{5}`. These do not work. How would on go about it?

Answer (score 3):

The argument of `\cline` has to be a *range* of columns, separated by `-`. If `\cline` is supposed to span just one column, state that column's number both before and after `-`.

For the table at hand, what you need to enter is `\cline{1-3} \cline{5-5}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
first & second & third & fourth & fifth \\ 
\hline
1 & first  & two   & \multirow{5}{*}{list} 
                       & \\ \cline{1-3}\cline{5-5}
2 & second & three &   & \\ \cline{1-3}\cline{5-5}
3 & third  & four  &   & \\ \cline{1-3}\cline{5-5}
4 & fourth & five  &   & \\ \cline{1-3}\cline{5-5}
5 & fifth  & six   &   & \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Mico. This is exactly what I was looking for. It looks so simple, yet it was so far for me. I appreciate the time and effort.